# Doit-on dire « accro à » ou « accro de » ?

Tags: usage, prépositions

En français, dit-on « accro à » ou « accro de » ?

Je viens d'entendre aux informations

> Les Français sont accros de leurs animaux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Le *Petit Robert* 1993 date *accro* de 1980 et distingue deux sens :

> 1. Dépendant d'une drogue. *Elle est accro à l'héroïne.*
> 2. Passioné par (qqch.). *Les accros du jazz.*

La frontière entre les deux sens n'est pas très marquée, le deuxième est une désintensification du premier. Le choix d'exemple suggère *accro à* pour un besoin physiologique et *accro de* pour une passion, mais c'est peut-être une coïncidence.

Sur Google Books, *[accro à](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22accro%20%C3%A0%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2010&lr=lang_fr)* a environ 4 fois plus d'occurrences que *[accro de](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22accro%20de%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2010&lr=lang_fr)*. Les exemples ne montrent pas de différence d'usage concluante.

> [Chaque fois que vous éprouvez un grand besoin de prendre une tasse de café, vous êtes un accro de cette drogue.](http://books.google.com/books?id=YyN8GebnxbcC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22accro+de%22&source=bl&ots=ryFF5gHVA3&sig=1lsxZdu0XO6nIRakr7pAJYpyoKI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rKUuUIrjAsec0AWxloGABQ&ved=0CG4Q6AEwCQ) (Graham L. Patrick, trad. Paul Depovere, *Chimie pharmaceutique*)
> [je suis certaine que Léonardo est un accro de ces sites morbides](http://books.google.com/books?id=5fgaAQAAIAAJ&q=%22accro+de%22&dq=%22accro+de%22&source=bl&ots=I8mhbOhUcI&sig=sm64GOL4UJEzp_9n7mEw0M-RWhE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rbIuUKuVCee_0QWe-4HoDA&ved=0CF4Q6AEwBzgK) (Brigitte Aubert, *Une âme de trop*)
> [Vous êtes un accro de l'info mobile...](http://books.google.com/books?id=514EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=%22accro+de%22&source=bl&ots=eSABObZ9hr&sig=j4CwGM0LudebAZUgfWL6ER7NwBI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rKUuUIrjAsec0AWxloGABQ&ved=0CEwQ6AEwAw) (Mobiles magazine, fév. 2004)
>
> [La société occidentale est totalement accro à la télévision.](http://books.google.com/books?id=uCuesCORjdsC&pg=PA449&lpg=PA449&dq=%22accro+%C3%A0%22&source=bl&ots=YitHZtoQ3L&sig=PoZbIh4e56gLvV-Wj74V8cDKMVY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=paUuUMPvN8HW0QW954CADQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBg) (Susan T. Fiske, trad. Valérie Provost et Sophie Huyghues Despointes, *Psychologie sociale*)
> [Vous êtes accro à la bouteille.](http://books.google.com/books?id=4PY2fGc_mhcC&pg=PT140&lpg=PT140&dq=%22accro+%C3%A0%22&source=bl&ots=n3ttvM28nj&sig=_DGYZMTdULrqKzAoO8-qUYU8JzM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FrQuUNfqBoi90QXa2oHgDA&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCDgK) (Patrick Bauwen, *L'œil de caïne*)
> [Accro à l'info ? Accédez depuis votre terminal [...]](http://books.google.com/books?id=814EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22accro+%C3%A0%22&source=bl&ots=R-LE-hr73v&sig=WJAZF7Zj4MrI5WlTxhCd4rE8KMs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XrMuUKaML4nB0QWSlYDgDA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwADha) (Mobiles magazine, avr. 2004)

J'en conclus qu'il n'y a pas lieu d'être accro à ou de l'une ou l'autre préposition.

Comment: La grande différence (même si elle n'est pas si grande) est que dans "accro à" accro est un adjectif, alors que dans "accro[s] de" accro est un nom. "Vous êtes **un** accro de l'information mobile" vs "Vous êtes accro à l'information mobile".

Comment: @dda « Accro » pourrait aussi être un adjectif nominalisé (comme « passionné ») dans la première phrase, et un nom attribut dans la deuxième. La frontière est assez floue et je ne vois pas comment elle pourrait justifier grammaticalement une différence de préposition.

Answer (score 5):

Je pense que l'expression *Les Français sont accros de leurs animaux.* est fautive, et qu'on dit *Les Français sont accros à leurs animaux* ou *Les Français sont des accros de leurs animaux.*

C'est le même fonctionnement que *passionnés*, tantôt nom, tantôt participe : *Les Français sont passionnés par leurs animaux*, *Les Français sont des passionnés de leurs animaux*.

Dans les exemples de Gilles, tous les accros avec *à* sont des participes, tandis que tous les accros avec *de* sont des noms (il me semble sous toutes réserves).

(oui, mais pourquoi on dit passionnés **par**, et accro **à** ? ) (...joker).

Comment: C'est une théorie intéressante, mais je n'ai pas l'impression qu'elle soit validée par l'usage, c'est juste un hasard que les exemples que j'ai choisis marchent. Pour *passionné*, on utilise *par* lorsque c'est le participe passé utilisé pour former un verbe au passif. Pour *accro*, la préposition *à* vient de « accroché à ». Il est possible que *à* soit la préposition « étymologique » et que *de* soit venue plus tard pour complémenter le nom, mais 30 ans après je n'ai pas l'impression que l'usage fasse cette distinction.

Comment: @Gilles: en regardant vite fait les quelques premières pages des liens google books que tu donnes, tous vérifient *participe + à* et *nom + de*. Intuitivement j'aurais donné exactement la même réponse qu'Istao. L'expression donnée en exemple reste pour moi incompréhensible, je ne saurais lui attribuer aucun des deux sens que tu mentionnes.

Comment: [Avec Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%2B%22accro+de%22&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=%2B%22accro+de%22&sc=8-11&sp=-1&sk=), on trouve plein d'_accro de_ sur des titres : accro de la mode, accro de scrap, accro de nature, accro de shopping... (c'est souvent pour des thèmes à caractère féminin, d'ailleurs ?? ) je ne sais pas trop ce que ça veut dire pour mes petites théories ; par contre, on trouve _Journal stylé d'une accro de la mode_. Ouf.

Answer (score 1):

Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accro) indique que :

```
accro (de accroché), adj
```

[Wikipédia](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accr) indique qu'il s'agit d'une

```
apocope de la dernière syllabe
```

Or on ne dit jamais "accroché de" mais toujours "accroché à". Ainsi donc, je pense que l'on doit dire accro à *qqch*. Sauf si l'usage en a décidé autrement à un moment donné.

Comment: Justement, l'usage a très vite décidé que *accro* pouvait se construire comme des quasi-synonymes tels que *passionnés*. Le fait que le verbe *accrocher* se construise avec *à* ne préjuge de la construction de *accro* qu'étymologiquement.

Answer (score -6):

Il faut dire : «accro à» et non ce que vous avez entendu à la radio...

Comment: Pourquoi ? Cette réponse manque de références.

Comment: Et alors? C'est la bonne réponse. Merci de ta contribution.